# If I am connected with two network then which network will be used for communication?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dns, ip

First I connect with a WIFI (to get internet connectivity) and then I connect with my company's network using Pulse Secure. When I do ipconfig then I get an output something like below:

```
C:\Users\himanshu.agrawal>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : groupinfra.com
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5ae5:4ee4:b357:f578%20
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.208.102.212
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::ed38:ca7c:4e6f:4559%17
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.231
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
```

What I want to understand is that:

1. When I am accessing internet sites then which network will be used - WIFI network or my company's network?
2. I know that the target website can see the IP address of the machine from which request has originated, so in my case the target website - - WIFI network (192.168.0.231) or my company's network (10.208.102.212)?

P.S.: I have asked this question on other networkengineering SO but it got closed and I couldn't get proper answer so asking here.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, any traffic out to the internet (or more specifically outside of either of the network ranges listed) will go via the Wireless connection, since that's the one where the Default Gateway is configured.

The Default Gateway basically tells the computer that if the destination is anywhere outside of your current networks, eg your computer doesn't know how to reach the destination, then the request will be sent to the Default Gateway (often your router) which will then handle directing the request to the correct destination.

The one exception to this could be if any manual routes have been added, perhaps the company network connection. In a command prompt you can run

```
route print
```

which will show your current IPv4 Route Table, with which you can see if any additional network ranges are configured to go via the 10.x.x.x interface.

In terms of any website visits, those won't show either of those IP addresses as they're both internal. The website will see the connection coming from whichever public IP address (eg the one provided by your ISP), so most likely the internet connection used by your Wifi.